# Using sqoop to import mysql data into HDFS through PHP but have some java version error

Tags: java, php, mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I trying to use sqoop to import mysql data into HDFS through PHP, I write a script which contains a sqoop command below:

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://my-database-ip/$1 --username myusername --password mypasswd --table $2 --fields-terminated-by " " -m 1

then I write a php file that call php exec() to execute this script, but when I call this .php from browser, the jobtracker shows "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" which might caused by different java version.

But it worked when I call this .php file using `php sqoop.php` from console

Does anyone have similarly experience or any advices?

P.S. I'm pretty sure that the apache user which is www-data in my ubuntu have the authority to run java, and both those java version in hadoop cluster and my web server are java1.6

Comment: You need Java 7 to run classes with version 51.0.

Comment: but all my computers are both running Java6 and the program is also compiled by Java6, why it still use version 51.0?
And it doesn't explain why it can worked on console but failed on browser